# post request - node js (tests) - java script

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, jasmine

I write a test which firstly has to do post request. I get an error when I run this :

the url is : 
    http://walla.com:8080/internal/getToken

the code :

```
function user(){
    var postData = {
        loginName: 'hello@gmail.com',
        password: 'abcdef'
    }

    var options = {
        host: 'http://walla.com',
        port: '8080',
        path: '/internal/getToken',
        body: postData
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    };

    var callback = function(response) {
        var str = ''
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            str += chunk;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log(str);
        });
    }

    var req = http.request(options, callback);
    req.end();
}



describe("ccc", function () {
    it("bbbb" , function(){
        user();
    });
});
```

Am i doing something wrong?
thanks?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma after the `body`

```
var options = {
    host: 'http://walla.com',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/internal/getToken',
    body: postData,                    // Note the Comma at the end
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
};
```

Instead, you can directly define the object, like this

```
var options = {
    host: 'http://walla.com',
    port: '8080',
    path: '/internal/getToken',
    body: {
        loginName: 'hello@gmail.com',
        password: 'abcdef'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

Comment: the missing ',' is typing error. I still get the error : 
"Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"
when i send those params to restclient of firefox it's work good...